# Action users number confusion

Tags: animation

I created previously 2 actions (animations) of my model, which I use in Unity. They both have visible number "3" near the "F" letter button, which I click that action would be saved. When I am adding now new actions and clicking "F" button it always appear "visible users number" not as "3" but as "2". These actions, which have "2" instead of "3" are not visible when I importing them to Unity.

Is there possible to change this "visible users number" that my new actions would be the same as these ones, which have "3" buttons instead of "2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number shown is called a user count. A user being defined as a data block (or object) in blender.

A new action will have one user, adding a fake user by clicking the 'F' button makes it 2 users, to get a third user you need to link it somewhere else, like to another object, a strip within the nla editor or an action constraint.

By dulicating an object with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (known as a linked copy) the new object will also be linked to the action. If this is the case then you may be importing the duplicate into unity not the one you added the new action to.

Comment: Well, it seems like it still does not solve my issue. But I made some more testings with another model, which does not have 3 users. However, as I posted the topic about "users", answering another question at the same time would be welcome. So here would be my [model](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/248943005/temp/knight2.blend), where is action named "1". Now it exports as FBX for unity perfectly. However, in action editor there is last column of keyframes. If I delete it, exported animation does not appear. What can it be so specific about this case?

Comment: I don't have unity but a guess is that for action '1' there is no movement between the first and second keyframes, so if you delete the third there is no movement. Maybe unity is smart enough to skip animations without any movement. I only see two users for all three actions.