# One animation is always played

Tags: animation

I'm pretty new to Blender and totally new on Stack so forgive the newbie question.

I made a simple model on blender with one animation and now I want to create another animation. Unfortunately the first animation is always here even when I click on the little "x" in the action editor to unlink this action. 
I mean when I select a frame, I got a pause from my previous animation even when I started a new one !

What am I missing here ?

the file : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lprc2ukyux113tb/Lemming.blend?dl=0

edit : I noticed that "the number of users of this data" (number between the action name and the "F") is 4 instead of the traditional 2. I don't know why, maybe this could help ?

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload blend files. Have you done research, duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66659/how-to-create-a-new-empty-action https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15886/action-users-number-confusion Do not ask two questions in a single question.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem myself : I've removed the action from the NLA Editor and everything works fine !

But I don't really understand what happened here, perhaps someone could give a more developed answer ?

Comment: You might simply have clicked one of the "push" and "stash" buttons around here: https://i.imgur.com/gL5cBU2.png